# Can not connect to tomcat java websocket remotely, but locally can

Tags: java, websocket

When deploying app locally on Tomcat 7.0.54 and then connect to ws://localhost:8080/request/subscription/messenger/xxxx
everything works just fine.

But when deploy as .war on remote server (Tomcat 8.0.18 - the websocket-api.jar is in lib folder) can not connect to, lets say 
ws://myshost.com:8080/request/subscription/messenger/xxxx

FF in FireBug outputs "can't establish a connection to the server"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myshost.com:8080/request/subscription/messenger/xxxx"

JS ws-client code:

```
            var webSocket;
            var messages = document.getElementById("messages");
            var token = document.getElementById("token").value;
//            var tokenTo = document.getElementById("token_to").value;
            var subscrContext = document.getElementById("context").value;
            var host = document.getElementById("host").value;
//            var port = document.getElementById("port").value;

            function openSocket(){
                // Ensures only one connection is open at a time
                if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
                    writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                    return;
                }
                // Create a new instance of the websocket
                var wsUrl = "ws://"+host+":8080/request/subscription/"+subscrContext+"/"+token;
                console.log(wsUrl);
                webSocket = new WebSocket(wsUrl);

                /**
                 * Binds functions to the listeners for the websocket.
                 */
                webSocket.onopen = function(event){
                    // For reasons I can't determine, onopen gets called twice
                    // and the first time event.data is undefined.
                    // Leave a comment if you know the answer.
                    if(event.data === undefined) 
                        return;

                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
//                  var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };
            }

            /**
             * Sends the value of the text input to the server
             */
            function send(){
                var text = document.getElementById("messageinput").value;
//                var json = {
//                  'action':'send_message', 
//                  'uid':123,
//                  'text':text
//                };
                webSocket.send(text);
            }

            function closeSocket(){
                webSocket.close();
            }

            function writeResponse(text){
                messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + text;
            }

            function clear() {
              messages.innerHTML = '';
            }
```

Java ws-server-endpoint code

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/subscription/{context}/{token}", encoders = {MessageEncoder.class}, decoders = {MessageDecoder.class})
public class SubscriptionServer implements Commons {

  private Queries q;

//  private ByteBuffer buff;

  private int currentUserId;

  private static final int           
          ERR_REQ_PARAM = 802;

  // storing sessions for messenger
  public static Map<Integer, Session> usersMessenger = new HashMap<>(),
  // storing sessions for road
  usersRoad = new HashMap<>();

  public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> userPosts = new HashMap<>();

  private static final Map<Integer, String> 
          errUserMsg = new HashMap<>(), 
          errSysMsg = new HashMap<>();

  private String token;

  private final static String 
          CONTEXT_MESSENGER = "messenger", 
          CONTEXT_ROAD = "road";

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(@PathParam("context") String context,
          @PathParam("token") String grossToken, Session sess) throws IOException,
          ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, EncodeException, JSONException {

    token = Helper.getToken(grossToken);
    currentUserId = Helper.getUserId(grossToken);    

    Logger.log("open user: "+currentUserId);

//    sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(
//            new JSONObject().put("token", token).put("uid", currentUserId));

    q = new Queries();

    if (q.checkToken(token, currentUserId) > 0) {

      subscribeUser(currentUserId, sess, context);

      sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new JSONObject()
              .put("token", token).put("user_id", currentUserId));
    } else {
      sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getErrorMessage(ERR_TOKEN, 
              "Этот аккаунт используется с другого устройства.", "Этот аккаунт используется с другого устройства."));
      sess.close();      
    }

//    System.out.println("User with id: " + sess.getId() + " has been connected!");

  }

  @OnMessage
  public void onMessage(@PathParam("context") String context, JSONObject json, Session sess) throws IOException, JSONException, EncodeException {

//    System.out.println("User with sid: "+sess.getId()+" sending msg:"+json.getString("text"));
//    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(msg);
//    Logger.log(json.toString());
//    sess.getBasicRemote().sendText("Received message:"+json);

    // ping - pong 
    if (json.has("ping") && json.getInt("ping")==1) {
      sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new JSONObject().put("pong", 1));
      return;
    }

    switch (context) {
      case CONTEXT_MESSENGER:
        sendMessageEvent(json.getInt("user_id"), json, sess);
        break;
      case CONTEXT_ROAD:
        sendRoadEvents(currentUserId, json, sess);
        break;
    }

//    String message = "Received message int bytes: "+msg;
//    
//    byte[] bytes = message.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
//    
//    buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length+1);
//    
//    buff.put(bytes);
//    
//    sess.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(buff);
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session sess, CloseReason reason, @PathParam("context") String context)
          throws IOException, JSONException, EncodeException {
    unsubscribeUser(currentUserId, context);
    sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess(new JSONObject().put("reason", "ServerEndpoint timeout")));
  }

  private void subscribeUser(int userId, Session sess, String context) {

    Logger.log("subscribe user: "+userId);

    SubscriptionQueries subscrQueries = new SubscriptionQueries();

    try {
      // check tmp memory table - send if contains some      
      List<String> jsonList = subscrQueries.getSubscriptionTmp(userId);

      if (!jsonList.isEmpty()) {
        sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new JSONObject().put("success", jsonList));
      }

      switch (context) {
        case CONTEXT_MESSENGER:
          usersMessenger.put(userId, sess);
          sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess());
          break;
        case CONTEXT_ROAD:
          usersRoad.put(userId, sess);
//          int startIndex = (request.getParameter("start_index") == null) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("start_index"));
//          int quantity = (request.getParameter("quantity") == null) ? 20 : Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("quantity"));
          // last 20 posts user sees when open road
          int startIndex = 0;
          int quantity = 20;
          List<Integer> posts = subscrQueries.getUserPosts(startIndex, quantity);
          userPosts.put(userId, posts);
          sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess());
          break;
      }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException | JSONException | EncodeException ex) {
      Logger.log(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()), "error.log");
      Logger.log(ex.getMessage(), "error.log");
    }

  }

  private void unsubscribeUser(int userId, String context) throws JSONException, IOException, EncodeException {

    Session sess;

    switch (context) {
      case CONTEXT_MESSENGER:
        sess = usersMessenger.remove(userId);
        sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess());
        break;
      case CONTEXT_ROAD:
        sess = usersRoad.remove(userId);
        userPosts.remove(userId);
        sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess());
        break;
    }
  }

  private void sendMessageEvent(int userId, JSONObject json, Session sess) throws IOException, EncodeException, JSONException {

    if (usersMessenger.containsKey(userId)) {

      Session userSess = usersMessenger.get(userId);
      userSess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(json);

    } else { // tmp memory tbl in DB
      SubscriptionQueries subscrQueries = new SubscriptionQueries();
      try {
        subscrQueries.setSubscriptionTmp(userId, json.toString());
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        Logger.log(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()), "error.log");
        Logger.log(ex.getMessage(), "error.log");
      }
    }

    sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess());

  }

  private void sendRoadEvents(int currentUserId, JSONObject json, Session sess) throws JSONException, IOException, EncodeException {
    // send to all users online, that where subscribed on these (say 20 last) posts
    // likes, comments, deletes, comment responses
    int userId;
    Session userSess;

    if (json.isNull("post_id")) {
      sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getErrorMessage(ERR_REQ_PARAM, 
              "Нет обязательного параметра post_id", "Нет обязательного параметра post_id"));
      return;
    }

//    sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new JSONObject().put("User Roads: ", usersRoad));
//    
//    sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new JSONObject().put("Users posts: ", userPosts));   

      for (Entry<Integer, Session> user : usersRoad.entrySet()) {

        userId = user.getKey();
        userSess = user.getValue();

        // ensure - not equals to this user 
        if (currentUserId != userId && userPosts.containsKey(userId)) {

          List<Integer> posts = userPosts.get(userId);

          sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(new JSONObject().put("Users posts: ", posts));

          if (!posts.isEmpty() && posts.contains(json.getInt("post_id"))) {

            userSess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(json);

          }

        }

      }
      // success after all
      sess.getBasicRemote().sendObject(Helper.getSuccess());

  }

  private void setErrors() {

    errSysMsg.put(ERR_REQ_PARAM, "Нет обязательного параметра");
    errUserMsg.put(ERR_REQ_PARAM, "Нет обязательного параметра");

  }

}
```

The server is running 100% - checked it several times with http requests to other contexts with Servlets that has been defined in web.xml - everything is standard and every request is working.

Comment: What the hack? People where are U? Does anybody help me with this. No body knows how works sockets weeeee....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was smart and simple as it should be:

1) extend HttpServlet

2) Override doGet method to receive GET with params

It is needed to get WebSocket handshake and Upgrade headers.

PS but on localhost it worked ok without HttpServlet and doGet, because it is the same machine and socket-server opened on localhost (say on port 8080) do not need a handshake over http, this thing is difficult to determine - I hope it would be helpful for someone.

Comment: Please show us the code, we are having similar problems here.